# Why is java identifying my doubles as "not initialized"?

Tags: java

I have a question regarding java's initializing, and I do not know why java thinks that the double in my program is not initialized, even though I have initialized it. Can someone please explain to me how to resolve this problem? In the code below, java says that double "inC" is not initialized.

```
package tempconverter;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class TempConverter extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener
{
    static String[] choices = { "From Celsius", "From Fahrenheit", "From Kelvin", "From Rankine" };
    static JFrame f = new JFrame("Temperature Converter");
    static JTextField enter = new JTextField(5);
    static JButton confirm = new JButton("Convert");
    static JComboBox choose = new JComboBox(choices);
    static JFrame tell = new JFrame();
    static JLabel one = new JLabel();
    static JLabel two = new JLabel();
    static JLabel three = new JLabel();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Font main = new Font("Comic Sans", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        confirm.addActionListener(new TempConverter());
        confirm.setFont(main);
        choose.setFont(main);
        enter.setFont(main);
        choose.addItemListener(new TempConverter());
        f.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setSize(340, 60);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(enter);
        f.add(confirm);
        f.add(choose);
        tell.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        tell.add(one, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tell.add(two, BorderLayout.WEST);
        tell.add(three, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        tell.setSize(160, 65);
        tell.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        double toConvert = Double.parseDouble(enter.getText());
        double inF, inK, inC, tempF = 0, tempK, inR, tempR;
        double tempC;

        if (choose.getSelectedItem().equals("From Celsius"))
        {
            tempF = toConvert * 1.8 + 32;
            tempK = toConvert + 273.15;
            tempR = (toConvert + 273.15) * 1.8;
            inF = Math.round(tempF * 100.00) / 100.00;
            inK = Math.round(tempK * 100.00) / 100.00;
            inR = Math.round(tempR * 100.00) / 100.00;
            one.setText(toConvert + "°C = " + inF + "°F");
            two.setText(toConvert + "°C = " + inK + "°K");
            three.setText(toConvert + "°C = " + inR + "°R");
            tell.setVisible(true);
        }

        if (choose.getSelectedItem().equals("From Fahrenheit"))
        {
            if (toConvert == 32)
            {
                inC = 0;
                inK = 273.15;
                inR = toConvert + 459.67;
                one.setText(toConvert + "°F = " + inC + "°C");
                two.setText(toConvert + "°F = " + inK + "°K");
                three.setText(toConvert + "°F = " + inR + "°R");
            }
            else
                tempC = (toConvert - 32) / 1.8;
            tempK = (toConvert - 32) / 1.8 + 273.15;
            tempR = toConvert + 459.67;
            inC = Math.round(tempC * 100.00) / 100.00;
            inK = Math.round(tempK * 100.00) / 100.00;
            inR = Math.round(tempR * 100.00) / 100.00;
            one.setText(toConvert + "°F = " + inC + "°C");
            two.setText(toConvert + "°F = " + inK + "°K");
            three.setText(toConvert + "°F = " + inR + "°R");
            tell.setVisible(true);
        }

        if (choose.getSelectedItem().equals("From Kelvin"))
        {
            tempC = toConvert - 273.15;
            tempF = tempC * 1.8 + 32;
            tempR = toConvert * 1.8;
            inC = Math.round(tempC * 100.00) / 100.00;
            inF = Math.round(tempF * 100.00) / 100.00;
            inR = Math.round(tempR * 100.00) / 100.00;
            one.setText(toConvert + "°K = " + inC + "°C");
            two.setText(toConvert + "°K = " + inF + "°F");
            three.setText(toConvert + "°K = " + inR + "°R");
            tell.setVisible(true);
        }

        if (choose.getSelectedItem().equals("From Rankine"))
        {
            if (toConvert == 0)
            {
                tempF = toConvert - 459.67;
                tempK = toConvert * (5 / 9);
                inF = Math.round(tempF * 100.00) / 100.00;
                inR = Math.round(tempK * 100.00) / 100.00;
                one.setText("0°R = -273.15°C");
                two.setText("0°R = " + inF + "°F");
                three.setText("0°R = " + inR + "°K");
                tell.setVisible(true);
            }
            else
                tempC = (toConvert - 491.67) * (5 / 9);
            tempF = toConvert - 459.67;
            tempK = toConvert * (5 / 9);
            inC = Math.round(tempC * 100.00) / 100.00;
            inF = Math.round(tempF * 100.00) / 100.00;
            inR = Math.round(tempK * 100.00) / 100.00;
            one.setText(toConvert + "°R = " + inC + "°C");
            two.setText(toConvert + "°R = " + inF + "°F");
            three.setText(toConvert + "°R = " + inR + "°K");
            tell.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Java points out that I have not initialized "inC" in the else statement of the "From Fahrenheit" and the "From Rankine" method. However, when I initialize it in the variable declaration, it doesn't change when I try to change it in the if-else statement and the methods. How do I fix this?

Comment: Assign a value to it when you declare it.

Comment: Seems to me you're misusing `else` without braces.

Comment: Like @kviiri says, you're missing braces, `{}` for the else statement you mentioned (why didn't you look for mistakes there?) And indent your code.

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't change its value later on in the code.

Comment: I can't even find the methods....

Comment: Yeah, very hard to read code formatted this way.

Comment: Solved the problem thanks and sorry

Answer (score 3):

I have copied yout example and i get the message at tempC. The reason is a missing `}` at the else path.

Change :

```
   else
        tempC = (toConvert - 491.67) * (5 / 9);
        tempF = toConvert - 459.67;
        tempK = toConvert * (5 / 9);
        inC = Math.round(tempC * 100.00) / 100.00;
        inF = Math.round(tempF * 100.00) / 100.00;
        inR = Math.round(tempK * 100.00) / 100.00;
        one.setText(toConvert + "°R = " + inC + "°C");
        two.setText(toConvert + "°R = " + inF + "°F");
        three.setText(toConvert + "°R = " + inR + "°K");
        tell.setVisible(true);
```

TO:

```
           else {
                tempC = (toConvert - 491.67) * (5 / 9);
                tempF = toConvert - 459.67;
                tempK = toConvert * (5 / 9);
                inC = Math.round(tempC * 100.00) / 100.00;
                inF = Math.round(tempF * 100.00) / 100.00;
                inR = Math.round(tempK * 100.00) / 100.00;
                one.setText(toConvert + "°R = " + inC + "°C");
                two.setText(toConvert + "°R = " + inF + "°F");
                three.setText(toConvert + "°R = " + inR + "°K");
                tell.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: But when I try to convert 1 rankine to celsius and kelvin it gives zero. Any help here?

Comment: @TessellatingPi change: `tempC = (toConvert - 491.67) * (5 / 9)` to `tempC = (toConvert - 491.67) * (5d / 9)` the `d` after 5 makes an double from 5 so it is not longer an interger division.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above the easiest thing would be to simply assign a value to it when you declare it.

The reason that Java thinks that it has not been initialized is that it might actually not have. You only ever assign it a value in one of the 4 outer most if-statements. If none of these four conditions are true, the variable will never be initialized.

And as Jens has also pointed out, you are missing a { after the "else".

Answer (score 0):

The actual cause of the error is dull: you're missing a brace.

**But**, let's look at `tempK = toConvert * (5 / 9);`. This will not do what you want since (5 / 9) will evaluate to 0 as the parentheses mean this is evaluated on its own and *in integer arithmetic*. To solve this, the easiest thing to do is remove the parentheses:

`tempK = toConvert * 5 / 9;`

so everything is computed in floating point. (Note that `*` and `/` have identical precedence).

You make this error a couple of times in your program.

Comment: +1 thanks now it works. I removed the brackets and added braces.